# Not able to install a software by invoking its exe from msi

Tags: installation, windows-installer, exe

I am trying to install a software as part of my product installation. My product installation is from an MSI file.I am trying to invoke the software installable exe from msi.

So when i launch msi, it invoked the exe and software installation began by extracting some packages. Later it started installing Microsoft VC++ 2010 x86 Redistributable setup. While installing vc++ package it is showing **"Waiting for another install to complete"** and installation did not continue.

So there is a deadlock state now. My msi file is invoking the exe and exe file is waiting for the msi (which is its originator) to complete.

So how should i go ahead and install a software from my msi file by invoking its executable file.

Can you please help me in fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ EXE you are trying to install is an MSI on the inside. You need a "bootstrapper" aka "chainer" to run it and then your MSI due to the fact that Windows Installer enforces a mutex of one InstallExecuteSequence per machine.